# Opening URL in browser using C++ with cocos2d-x in iOS

Tags: iphone, c++, ios, lua, cocos2d-x

I'm banging my brain against the wonderful lib xport that is cocos2d-x from the original cocos2d iOS library.

What I want to ask is how to open a web link in the safari browser? I don' know how to link the original objc code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:]];
```

I have tried using the LUA engine, that is capable of executing shell commands, but I cannot find the safari app path to launch it.

Thanks, people.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the paths to other applications. However, if you make that openURL: call to open a URL with the http:// domain then Safari will open it. Have you tried that? What result do you get?

UPDATE:
Caveat: I'm not sitting in front of a machine where I can test this.

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];
```

That should be all that is required. UIKit will switch to Safari and browse to the supplied URL.

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet of how should I call that function from my c++ code? Do I have to copy/import any new library to the project?

Comment: Hang on, give me a moment to chew over this. Realised that you're in C++, so the Objective-C above won't be of help.

Comment: I've had a quick look at the cocos2d site and see that it is Objective-C. Pop my two-line sample code into a C++ function in an Objective-C++ file (.mm extension) and try to call that from your 'plain' C++ code.

Comment: We have found a workaround in the [cocos2d-x forums](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/8602?r=8659#message-8659) that also includes using obj-c code, but I would also like another possible solutions.